# Groovy map and Java map on Generics

Tags: java, groovy

I am new to Groovy, and I have a question regarding to the use of map:

I know I can do:

`def map = [key:"value"]`

But what does it mean if I do this:

`Map<String, String> map = ["1":1, "2":"2"]`

This code compiles, but the map is not really a String->String map:

`map.each({println it.key + ":" + it.value + "[" + it.value.class + "]"})`

It prints:

> 1:1[class java.lang.Integer]
>
> 2:2[class java.lang.String]

Can anyone helps me to understand how come a map explicitly typed with String->String can be assigned to a map object that contains String->Integer? Thank you!

=== Update ===

Thanks for the link provided by @GrailsGuy, if I am using [@TypeChecked](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/TypeChecked.html) for the above code wrapped in a method, it will throw an error:

`[Static type checking] - Incompatible generic argument types. Cannot assign java.util.Map <java.lang.String, java.io.Serializable> to: java.util.Map <String, String>`

The explanation makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [forum post](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Not-enforcing-generic-type-td5438763.html) talks about Groovy ignoring generics, specifically:

> Groovy is a dynamically typed
>   language, but you can statically declare the types of variables.
>   Generics on the JVM are erased at compile time and only the raw type
>   is available to the VM (this is true both for groovy and Java).  In
>   Java, there is compile time checking to ensure that you don't stuff an
>   int into a list of strings.  But, Groovy does not check types at
>   compile time.
>
> So, this means that the type parameter is not checked at compile time
>   and not available at runtime.

Comment: hmm... then what's the point to allow generic syntax in groovy?

Comment: @zhong.j.yu To keep the compiler syntax checker heppy. Very little type enforcement is done especially at compile time. Groovy is very loose in terms of type enforcement and makes extensive use of `Object` types

Comment: wouldn't the compiler be happier if it doesn't support generics at all?

Comment: Thank you @GrailsGuy, the post mentioned TypeChecked annotation, which is very interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Eric,

I suspect this is caused by type erasure explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens). Since groovy is compiled into byte code, at the byte code level the parameterized types are removed. Thus,

`Map<String, String> objMap is compiled into Map objMap`.

Thus it is composed by keys and object values.This is the reason why groovy code compiles and runs without errors.
Hope this helps.