# Are List and List<String> the same in Groovy?

Tags: list, arraylist, groovy

**Question 1**

Is it irrelevant whether a `List` (list of objects) or a `List<String>` (list of Strings) is used in Groovy?

In the code example below, both lists end up being an `ArrayList` (ArrayList of objects). Would have expected the second list to be an `ArrayList<String>` (ArrayList of Strings).

Does Groovy lose the type information when the class is compiled and infer it when the compiled class is executed?

**Example 1**

```
List untypedList = ["a", "b", "c"]
List<String> typedList = ["a", "b", "c"]

println "Untyped list List:       ${untypedList.getClass()}"
println "Typed list List<String>: ${typedList.getClass()}"
```

**Output 1**

```
Untyped list List:       class java.util.ArrayList
Typed list List<String>: class java.util.ArrayList // Would have expected ArrayList<String>
```

**Question 2**

I would have expected the line `typedList << new Integer(1)` in the example below to fail with an exception because I'm trying to put an `int` into a list of Strings. Can anyone explain why I can add an `int` to the `String`-typed `List`?

The output shows that it remains an `Integer`, i.e. it's not on-the-fly converted to a `String` "1".

**Example 2**

```
List untypedList = ["a", "b", "c"]
List<String> typedList = ["a", "b", "c"]

untypedList << new Integer(1)
typedList << new Integer(1) // Why does this work? Shouldn't an exception be thrown?

println "Types:"
println "Untyped list List:       ${untypedList.getClass()}"
println "Typed list List<String>: ${typedList.getClass()}"

println "List contents:"
println untypedList
println typedList

println "Untyped list:"
untypedList.each { println it.getClass() }
println "Typed list:"
typedList.each { println it.getClass() }
```

**Output 2**

```
Types:
Untyped list List:       class java.util.ArrayList
Typed list List<String>: class java.util.ArrayList
List contents:
[a, b, c, 1]
[a, b, c, 1]
Untyped list:
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.Integer
Typed list:
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755261/groovy-map-and-java-map-on-generics

Comment: @tim_yates: So the answer according to the link you posted is "[...] this means that the type parameter is not checked at compile time and not available at runtime." which means I can't prevent anybody from putting an `int` into that `List<String>` which in turn means all I can be sure of is that `List<String>` contains objects of type `object`. Correct?

Comment: Yes. Unless you're using `@CompileStatic`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When running Groovy *"normally"*, generics are thrown away before compilation, so only exist in the source as helpful reminders to the developer.

However, you can use `@CompileStatic` or `@TypeChecked` to make Groovy honour these Generics and check the types of things at compilation.

As an example, consider I have the following project structure:

```
project
 |---- src
 |      |---- main
 |             |---- groovy
 |                    |---- test
 |                           |---- ListDelegate.groovy
 |                           |---- Main.groovy
 |---- build.gradle
```

With the code:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.1'
}

task( runSimple, dependsOn:'classes', type:JavaExec ) {
    main = 'test.Main'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

**ListDelegate.groovy**

```
package test

class ListDelegate<T> {
    @Delegate List<T> numbers = []
}
```

**Main.groovy**

```
package test

class Main {
    static main( args ) {
        def del = new ListDelegate<Integer>()
        del << 1
        del << 'tim'
        println del
    }
}
```

Now, running `gradle runSimple` gives us the output:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:runSimple
[1, tim]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.644 secs
```

So as you can see, the generics were thrown away, and it just worked adding `Integers` and `Strings` to out `List` of supposedly only `Integers`

Now, if we change `ListDelegate.groovy` to:

```
package test

import groovy.transform.*

@CompileStatic
class ListDelegate<T> {
    @Delegate List<T> numbers = []
}
```

And run again:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:runSimple
[1, tim]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.868 secs
```

We get the same output!!  This is because whilst `ListDelegate` is now statically compiled, our `Main` class is still dynamic, so still throws away generics before constructing the `ListDelegate`...  So we can also change `Main.groovy` to:

```
package test

import groovy.transform.*

@CompileStatic
class Main {
    static main( args ) {
        def del = new ListDelegate<Integer>()
        del << 1
        del << 'tim'
        println del
    }
}
```

And now re-running `gradle runSimple` give us:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy
startup failed:
/Users/tyates/Code/Groovy/generics/src/main/groovy/test/Main.groovy: 10:
    [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method test.ListDelegate#leftShift(java.lang.String).
    Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists.
 @ line 10, column 9.
           del << 'tim'
           ^

1 error

:compileGroovy FAILED
```

Which is, as you'd expect, failing to add a `String` to our declared List of `Integer`.

In fact, you only need to `CompileStatic` the `Main.groovy` class and this error will be picked up, but I always like to use it where I can, not just where I need to.

Comment: Awesome answer Mr. Yates!

Comment: Extremely useful, if my method returns a list of [boolean, String], in the method definition should I omit return type or put it as `List` ?

Comment: I'd wrap that in a new class that has a Boolean and a string in it 

Answer (score 4):

As @tim_yates notes, it is possible to enable compile time checks with the `@TypeChecked`/`@CompileStatic` annotations.

Another alternative is to enable runtime type checking by wrapping the collection with [`Collections.checkedList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedList%28java.util.List,%20java.lang.Class%29).  While this doesn't use the generics or the declared type, enforcing it at runtime sometimes fits in better with loosely typed dynamic code.  This is a Java platform feature not specific to groovy.

Example:

```
// no type checking:
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list1 << 1
assert list1 == ["a", "b", "c", 1]
// type checking
list2 = Collections.checkedList(["a", "b", "c"], String)
list2 << 1
// ERROR java.lang.ClassCastException:
// Attempt to insert class java.lang.Integer element into collection with element type class java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), for Java:

> Generics are checked at compile-time for type-correctness. The generic
>   type information is then removed in a process called [type
>   erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). For example, List will be converted to the
>   non-generic type List, which ordinarily contains arbitrary objects.
>   The compile-time check guarantees that the resulting code is
>   type-correct.

This type information is for compiler and IDE. Groovy is based on Java and inherits same principles for generics.

At other hand, Groovy is more dynamic language, so probably, it's the reason why it doesn't check types on compile time. IMO for Groovy it's some kind of code comment, sometimes very useful.

PS @tim_yates suggested a link to [Groovy docs about Generics](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Generics), that confirms:

> Groovy currently does a little further and throws away generics information "at the source level".